# How to run javascript commands

Tags: puppeteer

I am using `Cheerio` to parse the html and then running the following:

```
+$("#price1").text()|| +$("#price2").text() || undefined
```

Basically it tries to get the prices if the first fails and finally returns undefined if all fails.

How can I do the same thing in `Puppeteer`? I am not sure how to use `page.evaluate` to execute this chain of `if-else` commands. (I am also using Typescript as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the analog would be something like this:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://example.org/'); // your URL here

  const price = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const element = document.querySelector('#price1') ||
                    document.querySelector('#price2');
    if (element) return Number(element.innerText);
    return undefined;
  });
  console.log(price);
} catch(err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the assist, but when I tried it, I get `Property 'innerText' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)`, any idea how to solve this? When casting it to `any`, I am getting a `NaN` despite the price selectors being there as well..

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know TS(

Comment: There is also `.textContent`, but it is less readable sometimes: [`HTMLElement.innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) vs [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).

Comment: `.textContent` works (no complaints from Typescript) :D Thank you!